# I am getting a compile error: 6 not in list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying this small problem lists on codingbat. This is the link to the problem: http://codingbat.com/prob/p108886
 I have to compute the sum of the list except ignore a sublist which starts with 6 and ends with 7. I am sharing the code I have written, can anyone help me in where I am making a mistake.

```
def sum67(nums):
  def c6(six):
    if len(six) > 0:
      if 6 not in six:
        return six
      else:
        count= 0
        for a in six:
          if a== 6:
            count = count + 1

        for b in range(count):
          in1= six.index(6)
          in2= six.index(7)

          six= six[0:in1]+six[in2+1:]
        return six
    else:
      return 0

  a= c6(nums)
  return sum(nums)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* output from Python.

Comment: What if six-seven sequences are nested. Like `[6,6,3,7,7]`. The first one will remove the second six.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: I don't think the OP has the *secret test input*.

Comment: Thankyou for the edit Willem. I didn't consider that case, I will take that account now

Comment: But what about the compiling error that I am receiving?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I didn't ask for the input, but for the output of the Python interpreter. A syntax error from Python is more detailed than what's presented in the question.

Comment: @HilalFaiz Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to see the full error output from the Python interpreter. And we need to know on what line in the code you get the errors.

Comment: @HilalFaiz: that's not a compile error, that is a runtime error. Python has no compiler. It has an interpreter. The interpreter can also error on some syntax, but that is usally indentation errors, etc.

Comment: Compile error: 6 is not in list. @Someprogrammerdude this is the complete error from Python. you can che

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Python *is* (typically) compiled, just not to native machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the error for the list = [6,6,1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]

I have written the same code in tests.py and run with some examples.

I also found that `sum(nums)` needs to be changed to `sum(a)`

```
def sum67(nums):
    def c6(six):
        if len(six) > 0:
            if 6 not in six:
                return six
            else:
                count = 0
                for a in six:
                    if a == 6:
                        count = count + 1

                for b in range(count):
                    in1 = six.index(6)
                    in2 = six.index(7)

                    six = six[0:in1] + six[in2 + 1:]
                return six
        else:
            return 0

    a = c6(nums)
    return sum(a)


numbers = [6,6,1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]
sum1 = sum67(numbers)




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 26, in <module>
    sum1 = sum67(numbers)
  File "tests.py", line 21, in sum67
    a = c6(nums)
  File "tests.py", line 13, in c6
    in1 = six.index(6)
ValueError: 6 is not in list
```

Let me know if I am wrong.

I tried below code in my console. It's working for me all my inputs.

```
def sum67(nums):
    def c6(six):
        if len(six) > 0:
            if 6 not in six:
                return six
            else:
                count = 0
                for a in six:
                    if a == 6:
                        count = count + 1
                for b in range(count):
                    if six and six.__contains__(6) and six.__contains__(7):
                        in1 = six.index(6)
                        in2 = six.index(7)
                        six = six[0:in1] + six[in2 + 1:]
                return six
        else:
            return 0
    a = c6(nums)
    return sum(a)


numbers = [6, 6, 1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2,6,7]
sum1 = sum67(numbers)
print("Sum value = %s" % sum1)
Sum value = 6
```

But I am getting below error in the URL(http://codingbat.com/prob/p108886) provided in the main desription

```
Line 12: __contains__ is an invalid attribute name because it starts with "_".
```

So I don't know the reason for this error.

Comment: the reason for the error *(6 is not in list)* is that when there is a list having 6 at first position and 7 at last position and contains one more 6 in between, then count becomes 2 and first time six variable contains empty list and trying to find the 6 in the empty list for the next iteratio

Answer (score 0):

The error message you see is not, in fact, a compiler error. It is the value of the exception raised by `index` when the argument isn't found:

```
>>> [1,2,3].index(6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 6 is not in list
```

You need to catch the error and respond appropriately:

```
try:
    in1 = six.index(6)
except ValueError:
    # What should you do if there is no 6 in the list?
    # Do it here.
```